# How to address node-sass regression(?) "It's not clear which file to import for @import"

Tags: gruntjs, libsass, node-sass

It seems that a recent version of `node-sass` (3.4.1) breaks our build. I am consistently getting this error message:

```
It's not clear which file to import for '@import "../file"'.
Candidates:
     ../file.scss
     ../file.css
Please delete or rename all but one of these files.
```

Now, this is occuring for all the files in the project that have not explicitly specified "file.scss" in their name.

I have not been able to determine a fix for this bug - Nor can I find any documentation to address what has changed in `node-sass` to cause it. We have too many files for it to be practical to go rename each import.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

#### Edit:

This is also happening with files which have an underscore (eg. `_file`) in their path. Doesn't seem to recognize that these files are partials.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem, but only with `node-sass` version 3.4.2. Version 3.4.1 was working ok for me.

It seems this is a known issue in `node-sass` - https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/1222 however its not clear exactly which versions are affected.

I fixed it by uninstalling `grunt-sass`, then installing the exact version of `node-sass` that worked correctly (v3.4.1), and then finally reinstalling `grunt-sass`.

```
$ npm uninstall grunt-sass
$ npm install node-sass@3.4.1 --save-dev
$ npm install grunt-sass
```

This means `grunt-sass` uses your installed version, rather than installing its own version which it defines as `"node-sass": "^3.4.0"`

Weirdly even though I specified an exact version in the install command I still ended up with this in my package.json:

```
"node-sass": "^3.4.1"
```

So I manually changed that to the exact version so other developers in the team would get the correct version:

```
"node-sass": "3.4.1"
```

Of course if you find that the only version that works for you is v3.3.0 then use that that version in the instructions above.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up doing this as well, nice to know it's a well known problem. I regressed back to node-sass@3.3, glad to know @3.4.1 also works.

Answer (score 8):

### Option 1

You can import using the file extension

```
@import "../file.scss"
```

### Option 2

Or you can tell SASS not to generate the `.css` file by import without output. You have to rename the file from `file.scss` to `_file.scss`

That will let you import like this

```
@import "../file"
```

I prefer option 2 as it reduces the number of `css` files you have to keep track of.

Comment: "We have too many files for it to be practical to rename each @import". I could go throuh 100+ files, but it's not feasible. Downgrading node-sass to @3.3 solved the problem for me. I'm hoping there's a way to skirt this issue, as it never was a problem before.

Comment: We are already using the partial notation (`_file.scss`). This error is being thrown regardless.